# MySQL group multiple rows based on DISTINCT value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display the last 2 results from a table (results), the results are comprised of several rows with matching submissionId, The number of rows per submission is unknown, and of course I prefer a single query.

Here is the DB table structure

```
submissionId     input       value

     1           name         jay
     1           phone        123-4567
     1           email        test@gmail.com 
     2           name         mo
     2           age          32
     3           name         abe
     3           email        abe@gmail.com
     4           name         jack
     4           phone        123-4567
     4           email        jack@gmail.com
```

Desierd results:

```
submissionId     input       value

     3           name         abe
     3           email        abe@gmail.com
     4           name         jack
     4           phone        123-4567
     4           email        jack@gmail.com
```

Or even better, if I can combine the rows like this:

```
3           name         abe    3       email        abe@gmail.com
4           name         jack   4       phone        123-4567         4           email        jack@gmail.com
```

Comment: And by "last two results" you mean those with the greatest and second-greatest distinct `submissionId` values?

Comment: @vkp i tried this:  SELECT DISTINCT t1.submissionId
FROM results t1
LEFT JOIN results t2
ON t1.submissionId = t2.submissionId
GROUP BY t1.submissionId

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes (for now) Later on I'm planning to add a date column and get the 2 latest results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the query looks like now, so i can get the results with a LIMIT, RANGE, and id/timestamp (with help of Tim and Gordon):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM rmyTable t
 JOIN
 (SELECT DISTINCT sd.submissionId
 FROM myTable sd
 WHERE sd.questionId = yourId
 ORDER BY sd.submissionId 
 LIMIT 2
 ) t2 
 ON t.submissionId = t2.submissionId 
 WHERE t.formId = yourId
 AND dateTime BETWEEN 0000 AND 1111
```

Answer (score 2):

One option here is to use a subquery to identify the most recent and next to most recent `submissionId`:

```
SELECT submissionId, input, value
FROM yourTable
WHERE submissionId >= (SELECT MAX(submissionId) FROM yourTable) - 1
ORDER BY submissionId
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

**Update:**

If your `submissionId` column were really a date type, and you wanted the most recent two dates in your result set, then the following query will achieve that.  Note that the subquery in the `WHERE` clause, while ugly, is not correlated to the outer query.  This means that the MySQL optimizer should be able to figure out that it only needs to run it once.

```
SELECT submissionDate, input, value
FROM yourTable
WHERE submissionDate >=
    (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN submissionDate = (SELECT MAX(submissionDate) FROM yourTable)
                    THEN '1000-01-01'
                    ELSE submissionDate
               END) FROM yourTable)
ORDER BY submissionDate
```

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Getting back this error:  This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Your new query assumes that there are no gaps in the submissionId numbers.  It's unclear whether that's a safe assumption.  In any event, this approach will not work when the OP converts to a timestamp-based definition of "last two", as he now says in comments he intends ultimately to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It works great, but as i mentioned in the comment, the table has more columns that will be used for ON clauses like a date, question type etc.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I updated to include a query which will include the two most recent dates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Will this work on a UTC/GMT timestamp

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz If you're referring to the second query, the logic should work on any MySQL date/time type.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you so much, but how do I limit it based on the DISTINCT so let's say I only need the submissions of last week but only 5 and not all of them (what happens now is if I do limit 30 it gives me 30 rows, not 30 results regardless of row count)

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz This is the second time you've changed requirements, and unfortunately I don't have time right now to spit out another query.  You might want to ask a new question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `limit` in subqueries in the `from` clause, so a typical way to write this is:

```
SELECT submissionDate, input, value
FROM t join
     (select distinct submissionDate
      from t
      order by submissionDate desc
      limit 2
     ) sd
     on t.submissionDate = sd.submissionDate;
```

Comment: Thanks, with a little modification this worked as desired.

Comment: I will try to remember this next time I see a similar question.